# Solve`DirInf[] — Meaningful value or just a bug?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 4.1 or earlier and fixed in 12.3**

---

To the problem below, I get four independent, incomplete solutions, three in terms of `` Solve`DirInf[] ``.  Since `DirInf` is not in the `` System` ``  context, I assume this behavior is a bug (or not?).  But I was wondering if it made any sense as a solution.

```
Solve[Flatten@{
   NestList[
     D[#, x] &, (
      Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 5/3, (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])]^2 y[
        x]^2 (1 - (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])))/(
      C[1] - 8/3 I y[x]^(3/2)) == (x + C[2])^2, 1] /. {x -> 0},
   y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0},
 {C[1], C[2]}, {y[0], y'[0]}]
```

> Solve::ifun :  Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
>
> Solve::svars :  Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>
> ```
> {{C[1] -> -((8 I)/3)}, {C[1] -> (8 I)/3},
>  {C[1] -> -(8/(3 Sqrt[-1 + 2 Solve`DirInf[] - Solve`DirInf[]^2]))},
>  {C[1] -> 8/(3 Sqrt[-1 + 2 Solve`DirInf[] - Solve`DirInf[]^2])},
>  {C[2] -> 0}}
> ```

BTW, `Reduce` fails on the system.

FWIW, the problem arises from the following IVP:

```
y''[x]^2 == -4 y[x] && y[0] == 1 && y'[0] == 0
```

Comment: Bug. That's an internal symbol that should not appear in results.

Comment: A very old bug. Exactly the same output appear in Mathematica 5.2.0 and 8.0.4.

Comment: @innaiz Thank you for the info.

Comment: Almost the same output in v4.1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxWgq.png Another incorrect result (but with proper warning) in v3.0: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3mPU.png So this seems to be a bug since v4.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks!  I like the "should be checked by hand" in V3.  I haven't seen that lately.  It's funny, too, for how do you check `Indeterminate` by hand?  The warning should have come before we got to `Indeterminate`.

Comment: Sometimes one can check by taking a limit. `Solve` won't know this in the right places because it is at heart algebraic and "knows" no analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, it'a a bug. Two ways to get the result you want.

First omit the comand to eliminate `{y[0], y'[0]}`  in Solve. Since you explicitly set them Equal 1 and 0 and later want to eliminate it, Solve gets confused.

```
eqs = Flatten@{NestList[
 D[#, x] &, (Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 
       5/3, (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])]^2 y[
       x]^2 (1 - (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])))/(C[1] - 
     8/3 I y[x]^(3/2)) == (x + C[2])^2, 1] /. {x -> 0}, y[0] == 1,
y'[0] == 0}

Solve[eqs, {C[1], C[2]}]

(*   {{C[1] -> (8 I)/(
3 InverseFunction[Hypergeometric2F1, 4, 4][1/2, 2/3, 5/3, 0]), 
C[2] -> 0}}   *)
```

Second, set the y with Rule to wanted values to get the same result

```
Solve[Flatten@
  Evaluate@{NestList[
   D[#, x] &, (Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 
         5/3, (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])]^2 y[
         x]^2 (1 - (8 I y[x]^(3/2))/(3 C[1])))/(C[1] - 
       8/3 I y[x]^(3/2)) == (x + C[2])^2, 1] /. 
  x -> 0 /. {y[0] -> 1, y'[0] -> 0}}, {C[1], C[2]}, {y[0], y'[0]}
]
```

**Edit**

I am using version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"

@MichaelE2, you are right. Solve should be able to give solution for (but does not)

```
Solve[{c1 == y1, c2 == y2, y1 == 1, y2 == 0}, {c1, c2}]
```

Don't know why my first example works this time without command to eliminate the y.

Second, if you accept infinity as solution, C[1] -> +/- infinity together with C[2]==0 are solutions.

```
eqs2 = eqs /. {y[0] -> 1, y'[0] -> 0}

Plot[Evaluate@Through[{Re, Im}[eqs2[[1, 1]] /. C[1] -> c1]], {c1, -5, 
   5}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]

Limit[eqs2[[1, 1]], C[1] -> -\[Infinity]]

(*   0   *)

eqs /. {C[1] -> -\[Infinity], C[2] -> 0}

(*   {True, True, y[0] == 1, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0}   
*)
```

Comment: Tx! What version are you using?  I get an empty set `{}` for the first. That might be right and `InverseFunction[Hypergeometric2F1, 4, 4][1/2, 2/3, 5/3, 0]` be undefined. Some limiting value for `C[1]`, such as `Infinity`, might be a solution, but I haven't found one. For your second, I get that `Solve` cannot solve the equation. (V12.1.1, Mac) -- BTW the form in the OP was desired because `Solve` balks at simple things like `Solve[Flatten@Evaluate@{NestList[D[#, x] &, y[x] == C[1] Sin[x] + C[2] Cos[x],1] /. {x -> 0}, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, {C[1], C[2]}]`, for me. Might be different for you.

Comment: @MichaelE2, i am using version "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)". See my Edit above.